# Project structure of react-native application

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am starting working over react-native for development of android application. I am quite familiar with android studio structure. In android sdk to create `view` XML is present and for `controller` java is present. But in react-native how to create `view` and `controller` for android application ?

Comment: which IDE you are using for react native?

Comment: VS code or sublime text editor

Answer (score 0):

> But in react-native how to create view and controller for android application ?

This question is like given an apple but analyze as an orange.

For `react-native`, exactly for `React` part, we don't explicitly manage it as `view` and `controller` as we did for android or ios.

I suggest you read about `React` first. It is the core idea. The `Native` part is just meaning `build the native mobile app by React way` (you have totally 100% ways to touch the native part - android/ios code - without any restriction as you want).

Comment: In case you want to jump right to `react-native`, you can follow this course: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/overview . Please note, I am not author of that course, also not receive any benefit. It's just a course that I usually introduce to my co-workers when they asked me how to start learning `react-native`. it's a good course in my opinion only).